# How to solve the problem that the video is covered by the navigation bar after full screen

Tags: fullscreen, screen-orientation, react-native-video

[like this as follow,When I want to play in full screen, the video is overlaid behind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9HTM.png)

Comment: Please write your question here, not as a link.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this code to hide the navigation bar:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            mActivity.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN |
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
                    //View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
}
```

With fullscreen options you can hide status bar too and with Immersive sticky you can get the navigation and status bar again sliding your finger.

To remove this options use the following code:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            View decorView = mActivity.getWindow().getDecorView();
            int uiOptions = decorView.getSystemUiVisibility();

            uiOptions  &= ~View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN;
            uiOptions  &= ~View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
            uiOptions  &= ~View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
            uiOptions  &= ~View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;

            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use  [react-native-full-screen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-full-screen) which provide full screen control
You can put that on componentDidmount or useeffect method with     FullScreen.onFullScreen();